# How can I transpose duplicated values of a column to a specific position on a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to transpose a duplicated value on a column to a new column on the same row as the first result

#### Create Dataset

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

ref = ['a','a','b','c','c','c']

z = pd.DataFrame(ref)

z = z.rename(columns={0:'name'})
```

### Finding unique values {name, [index position, nº duplicates]}

```
unique_values = {}

i = 0

while i <= len(z)-1:

for x in z.name:
    if x not in unique_values:
        unique_values[x] = i,0
        i+=1
    else:
        unique_values[x] = unique_values[x][0] , unique_values[x][1]+1
        i+=1
```

### Here starts the problem:

###### I am trying to use unique_values as a guide of (index, and number of duplicates) to create a new column that has the duplicated value on the same row as the "first" value. dataset like this: name= ['a', 'b', 'c'] ;  name1=['a', na, 'c']; name2= [  na ,na 'c']

###### For some reason, i can't find the error of why this part doesn't work: Help pls

```
x = 1
i = 1
for k,v in unique_values.items():
if v[1] > 0:
    print(k,v,x)
    if x <= v[1]:
        z[f'name{x}'] = pd.Series(z.name.loc[z.index[v[0]+i]], index=z.index[[v[0]]])
        x+=1
        i+=1
    else:
        x = 1
        i = 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the last part of your code ?

Comment: I am trying to use unique_values as a guide of (index, and number of duplicates) to create a new column that has the duplicated value on the same row as the "first" value. Something like this: name= ['a', 'b', 'c']   name1=['a', na, 'c']. name2= [  na ,na ''c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem well, this should work:

```
Z=z.where(z.iloc[:,0].duplicated(keep='last'))
i=0
while sum(Z.notna().values)!=0 :
    W=Z.dropna().drop_duplicates()
    i+=1
    result=[]
    for j in range(len(z)):
        try:
            result.append(W.loc[j].values[0])
        except:
            result.append(np.nan)
    z[f'name{i}']=pd.Series(result)
    Z=Z.where(Z.duplicated(keep='last'))
print(z)
```

Comment: YES!! thats it! thank you so much! ;)

Comment: no worries, don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful!